# Central table in many to many hibernate relationship

Tags: hibernate, netbeans, many-to-many

I'm new in hibernate. I want to create many to many connection between book and author with hibernate in **netbeans**. All the examples I saw were for Eclipse And I could not find the answer of my question.
my Book.hbm.xml is:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="Book" table="books">
  <id name="bookId" type="int" column="BookID">
     <generator class="assigned"/>
  </id>
  <property name="isbn" column="Isbn" type="string"/>
  <property name="title" column="Title" type="string"/>
  <property name="bookPicPath" column="BookPicPath" type="string"/>
  <property name="summary" column="Summary" type="string"/>
  <property name="genry" column="Genry" type="string"/>
  <property name="parentGenry" column="ParentGenry" type="string"/>
  <set name="authors" table="Book_Author" cascade="all">
        <key column="BookID" />
        <many-to-many column="AuthorID"  class="Author" />
  </set>

</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and Author.hbm.xml is:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="Author" table="authors">
  <id name="authorId" type="int" column="AuthorID">
     <generator class="assigned"/>
  </id>
  <property name="fname" column="Fname" type="string"/>
  <property name="lname" column="Lname" type="string"/>
  <property name="biography" column="Biography" type="string"/>
  <property name="gender" column="Gender" type="string"/>
  <property name="website" column="Website" type="string"/>
  <property name="authorPicPath" column="AuthorPicPath" type="string"/>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

In main class i create tables like this:

```
HibernateUtil.droptable("drop table authors");
HibernateUtil.setup("create table authors ( AuthorID int, Fname VARCHAR(20), Lname VARCHAR(20), Biography VARCHAR(255), Gender VARCHAR(20), Website VARCHAR(255), AuthorPicPath VARCHAR(255))");
HibernateUtil.droptable("drop table books");
HibernateUtil.setup("create table books ( BookID int, Isbn VARCHAR(20), Title VARCHAR(255), BookPicPath VARCHAR(255), Summary VARCHAR(255), Genry VARCHAR(255), ParentGenry VARCHAR(255))");
```

my questions:

1.in many to many relationship There is a connection table(Book_Author).now  I must do it manually or hibernate creates its own?
2. in main class I have:

```
SessionFactory sessions = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
Session session = sessions.openSession();

    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();

        Set<Author> authors = new HashSet<Author>();
        Author a1 = new Author("1","1","1","1","1","1");
        Author a2 = new Author("2","2","2","2","2","2");
        authors.add(a1);
        authors.add(a2);

        Book b1= new Book("a","a","a","a","a","a",authors);
        session.save(b1);

        tx.commit();
        tx = null;           

    } catch ( HibernateException e ) {
        if ( tx != null )
            tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
```

but When I run the program, I see the following error:

```
a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [Author#0]
```

Please guide.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you use SchemaExport (aka hbm2ddl), hibernate can automatically generate the relation table 
   (`Book_Author`) for you. You can configure it in your `hibernate.cfg.xml` like this: `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>`
2. I see you used `<generator class="assigned"/>` for your id's. In this case you have to assign the id manually; if you don't, hibernate will throw that exception.